# xgboost in Python is not returning importance of features despite what is referred in the documentation

Tags: python, xgboost

According to the xgboost documentation (https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.training) the xgboost returns feature importances:

> **feature_importances_**
>
> Feature importances property
>
> **Note**
>
> Feature importance is defined only for tree boosters.  Feature importance is only defined when the decision tree model is chosen as base learner 
>   ((booster=gbtree). It is not defined for other base learner types, such as linear learners (booster=gblinear).
>
> **Returns:**  feature_importances_
>
> **Return type:**  array of shape [n_features]

However, this does not seem to case, as the following toy example shows:

```
import seaborn as sns
import xgboost as xgb

mpg = sns.load_dataset('mpg')

toy = mpg[['mpg', 'cylinders', 'displacement', 'horsepower', 'weight',
       'acceleration']]

toy = toy.sample(frac=1)

N = toy.shape[0]

N1 = int(N/2)

toy_train = toy.iloc[:N1, :]
toy_test = toy.iloc[N1:, :]

toy_train_x = toy_train.iloc[:, 1:]

toy_train_y = toy_train.iloc[:, 1]

toy_test_x = toy_test.iloc[:, 1:]

toy_test_y = toy_test.iloc[:, 1]

max_depth = 6
eta = 0.3
subsample = 0.8
colsample_bytree = 0.7
alpha = 0.1

params = {"booster" : 'gbtree' , 'objective' : 'reg:linear' , 'max_depth' : max_depth, 'eta' : eta,\
             'subsample' : subsample, 'colsample_bytree' : colsample_bytree, 'alpha' : alpha}

dtrain_toy = xgb.DMatrix(data = toy_train_x , label = toy_train_y)
dtest_toy = xgb.DMatrix(data = toy_test_x, label = toy_test_y)
watchlist = [(dtest_toy, 'eval'), (dtrain_toy, 'train')]

xg_reg_toy = xgb.train(params = params, dtrain = dtrain_toy, num_boost_round = 1000, evals = watchlist, \
                early_stopping_rounds = 20)

xg_reg_toy.feature_importances_
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-378-248f7887e307> in <module>()
----> 1 xg_reg_toy.feature_importances_

AttributeError: 'Booster' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'
```

Comment: have you tried with `xgboost sklearn`, because it works for me

Comment: Yes indeed the scikit learn API returns the feature importances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are using is [Learning API](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.training), but you are referencing to [Scikit-Learn API](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn). And only Scikit-Learn API have the attribute `feature_importances`.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who is not using Scikit-Learn API like me, because of obvious reasons.
From [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.Booster.get_score) I was able to get the importance of the feature:

```
clf.get_score()
```

Also, I was looking into a more intuitive representation [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.plot_importance):

```
from xgboost import plot_importance
plot_importance(clf, max_num_features=10)
```

This generates the bar chart with specified (optional) `max_num_features` in the order of their importance.